# How to connect wallet with walletconnet in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Well I just wanted to ask that is there any package for django python to connect wallet by scanning QR code in django. I am using web3.py but i didn't see any package for wallet connect. If there is such package then please share with me and tell me how is possible.